# Extracting discrete timestamp values of a dataset from a continous timestamps

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing, timestamp

I have a dataset with data points every minute, lets say df_cont with **Value** having cumulatively increasing numbers

```
                Value
datetimeindex  
09:00:00         34
09:01:00         45
09:02:00         48
09:03:00         50
.                .
.                .
.                .
18:58:00         55
18:59:00         65
19:00:00         68
```

I have another dataset with just time values, let's say df_time

```
Time_1       Time_2
09:05:00     09:15:00
10:05:00     10:25:00
11:55:00     12:15:00
17:05:00     17:15:00
```

Now, the difference has to be found out for "Value" in the timestamp of the difference in time between Time_1 and Time_2.

I can do this manually by using the DateTime functionality

```
df_cont["2020-5-14 09:05:00":"2020-5-14 09:15:00"].Value.max() - df["2020-5-14 09:05:00":"2020-5-14 09:15:00"].Value.min()
```

However, was unable to this automatically for all the difference of timestamps by either looping or using some other functions of pandas. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to join based on time_1 and time_2 and then calculate the difference. You might have to reset index in your case.

```
df_cont = pd.DataFrame({'time':[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], 'Value':[45, 48, 53, 55, 60, 64]})
df_time = pd.DataFrame({'time1':[1, 2, 5], 'time2':[3, 4, 6]})

df = (df_time.merge(df_cont.rename(columns={'time':'time1', 'Value':'value1'}), on='time1')
                  .merge(df_cont.rename(columns={'time':'time2', 'Value':'value2'}), on='time2'))

df['value_diff'] = df['value2'] - df['value1']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can groupby an [interval index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.IntervalIndex.html) using [`cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df_cont = pd.DataFrame(index=pd.date_range('09:00', '19:00', freq='T'))
df_cont['Value'] = df_cont.index.hour*100 + df_cont.index.minute
df_time = pd.DataFrame({'Time_1': {0: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-02 09:05:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-02 10:05:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-02 11:55:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-02 17:05:00')}, 'Time_2': {0: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-02 09:15:00'), 1: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-02 10:25:00'), 2: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-02 12:15:00'), 3: pd.Timestamp('2020-06-02 17:15:00')}})

idx = pd.IntervalIndex.from_arrays(df_time.Time_1, df_time.Time_2, 'both')
groups = pd.cut(df_cont.index, idx)
df_cont.groupby(groups).Value.apply(lambda x: x.max() - x.min())
```

Result:

```
[2020-06-02 09:05:00, 2020-06-02 09:15:00]    10
[2020-06-02 10:05:00, 2020-06-02 10:25:00]    20
[2020-06-02 11:55:00, 2020-06-02 12:15:00]    60
[2020-06-02 17:05:00, 2020-06-02 17:15:00]    10
```